# Why does not 'wrapfigure' and its paragraph show together?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

`wrapfig` is typically used with an intention to typeset it side by side with a certain text that should wrap it. However, when I use a lot of floats near `wrapfig`, a part of all of the text will not stay close to the wrapped figure. Also, the figure is not in order with the rest of others. How do I solve this?

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\commonfigwidth}{0.35\linewidth}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{\commonfigwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \centering This is a circuit
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

LaTeX will not think of `wrapfigure` as a float unless it is written inside `figure` environment. All what exists inside `figure` or `table` environment must be shown at once on any page that LaTeX selects for. Thus, a good workaround is

```
\begin{figure}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{<other wrapfig arguments>} 
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{<image file name>}
    \end{wrapfigure}

  <the text that should wrap the figure>

\end{figure}
```

That way, the paragraph(s) that are supposed to be near the wrapped figure will be forced to stay there even if the material around it has a lot of floats. Also, LaTeX will place all floats in the order they have appeared in the source code so this also solves the order issue mentioned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\commonfigwidth}{0.35\linewidth}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}

        \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{\commonfigwidth} 
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \centering This is a circuit
        \end{wrapfigure}

    \blindtext

    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\commonfigwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this moves the text to be out of order with the other text on the page so is only usable if the text is essentially an extended caption for the figure, it is not usable if the text is part of the main document flow.

Answer (score 2):

`wrapfigure` has no connection to the usual float mechanism so if you use both, you need to manage any issues that arise, here I think you get an acceptable output if you prevent the cutout carrying on the the next page, via

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}[8]{O}{\commonfigwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \centering This is a circuit
    \end{wrapfigure}
```

so restricting it to 8 lines (instead of the 10 that it would use by default)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is sometimes very necessary to guarantee that certain paragraph(s), even when they are long, stay very close to certain figures they describe (this is why many people want to use it instead of letting the figure float). I am not an expert, but I posted the question + answer because I wanted to share my experience working with this issue.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I hadn't seen you had posted an answer, to be honest I don't think it's an answer, as you have converted the main text from being part of the main document flow to an extended caption to the figure, of course using `\blindtext` it sort of looks OK either way but in practice I think it would be rather rare for a paragraph to be usable in either context.